# Issue with CentOS 6.4 – NX Client/OpenNX and keyboard configuration

Tags: linux, keyboard, centos, nx

since CentOS 6.4 was released yesterday, I started doing testing with it and found a weird issue, so I ask here in case somebody else can help me with a solution.

My setup

- Linux CentOS 6.3 Server + XFCE-4
- Remote access using NX Client from Windows 7. Also works with OpenNX.net client.
- I have an International keyboard, model: pc105 + layout: es, all keys are working fine, special chars, I didn't have to do anything special to get this working, it just works.

I run a `yum update`, all the new packages download, server now is running CentOS 6.4, no other changes in configuration.

The issue is that after the update, when I connect via NX Client or OpenNX.net, the keyboard is not being set, from what I see:

- Most of the keys appears to be a US keyboard
- Cannot type the letter "P" (seriously, it's the only letter I cannot type, nothing happens)

When I open a terminal and execute "setxkbmap" (have to access the server through ssh and create an script since cannot type the "p" in the command), this is the output:

```
Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
Use defaults: rules - 'base' model - 'pc105' layout - 'us'
```

Using one script I managed to execute:

```
setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout es
```

This fixes the issue with special chars, however I still cannot type the letter "P"

Other testing I have done:

- Installed another CentOS-6.4 (from 6.4 CD, no update)
- Keyboard map works fine in the main console, tested with GNOME (startx) and XFCE (startxfce4)
- Keyboard map works fine when accessing via XDMCP from other host
- The same keyboard issues if I install nx/freenx on the server and configure the access.

Comment: This is something you should report to CentOS bugzilla.

Comment: Reported on CentOS Bugs as http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6298

Comment: Please check your formatting – lists need to be formatted differently.

Answer (score 1):

Filed a bug with CentOS (http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6298) and it seems that this issue is related to this bug (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50553)

The problem is with the xkeyboard-config-2.6-6 package which is being included in CentOS-6.4.

UPDATE: An alternative solution, you can update all the packages to CentOS-6.4 and then run the command:

```
# touch /usr/share/X11/xkb/keymap.dir
```

Old Solution: 
In the mean time, my solution is to downgrade the package to the version used in CentOS-6.3 and exlude it from being updated again.

Download the old package from:
http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/x86_64/Packages/xkeyboard-config-2.3-1.el6.noarch.rpm

Force removal of the new package and install the old package:

```
rpm -e --force xkeyboard-config
rpm -ivh xkeyboard-config-2.3-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

To avoid the package being updated again, add the following line to /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo in the [base] section.

```
exclude=xkeyboard-config-*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Xfce 4.8, there are default key bindings for Super-p and Super-Tab which seems to cause problems for OpenNX. Apparently there is something which makes it seem like the Super key is stuck, but I don't know the underlaying issue for this unfortunately.

You can try to remove these bindings and see if this quick-fixes your problem:

```
sed -i '/property name="&lt;Super&gt;p"/d' \
  ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
sed -i '/property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab"/d' \
  ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```